# product website with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a product website with 80 pages. Its a product showcase and I have 70 products with its images and specifications. If its in html , I have to create 70 pages, i would like to do it in php and my sql. What I would like to do is , 
I will create a template for the product page.On click of each product name , the details of the  product such as image , product name , specifications should load. The strucute of the site site is like this

### home

### products

**category 1**

```
 product 1
 product 2
 product 3
 product 4
 product 5
 ....
 ....
 product 30
```

**category 2**

```
 product 1
 product 2
 product 3
 product 4
 product 5
 ....
 ....
 product 30
```

**category 3**

```
 product 1
 product 2
 product 3
 product 4
 product 5
 ....
 ....
 product 30
```

### contact

How can I do this with php and mysql. Basically i am a UI developer and I have some practical knowledge in php. I dont know mysql. Can anybody guide me where to start . Is there any tutorial available for this?

thanks a ton in advance
navii

Comment: look at some FOSS apps - drupal, joomla, wordpress etc

Comment: Have you already searched for PHP and MySQL tutorials? You should find plenty of them.

Comment: Please be a little more specific ... what have you already tried searching for / working with -- what problems are you having understanding what you have found already?

Answer (score 4):

Simplest solution would be to check out a CMS like Joomla! (http://joomla.org) or Drupal (drupal.org?)

Comment: Agree. But this could make styling more difficult.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Database-Articles/Create-dynamic-sites-with-PHP-MySQL/ - good old Google!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is way to general to give a good answer in 5 minutes.

There are many dozen ways you could implement what you describe. I would start looking into some of the frameworks available for developing this. But that is my preference.

I would start with the tutorials for:

- symfony http://www.symfony-project.org/
- doctrine http://www.doctrine-project.org/

and see if that could get you started.

otherwise:

- model your database with a 'categories' and a 'products' table
- create a php file you call template something and give it the extention .phtml if you feel like it
- create a script named product.php and let it take an argument like `product.php?id=23`
- in your script select the database for product with id=23 and populate your template with the data from the database.